# BigInteger - java.lang.NumberFormatException error?

Tags: java

I have a string and I am breaking that string into tokens and then I am converting the tokens into biginteger for further processing. 
I am getting  java.lang.NumberFormatException error

here is the code snippet

```
public void tokenize() {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expr);
    while ( st.hasMoreElements() ) {
        String val = st.nextElement().toString();
        if ( isOperator( val ) ) {
            operator.push(val);
        }
        else {
            BigInteger op = new BigInteger(val);
            operand.push(op);
        }
    }
}
```

The format of expression is like this

```
4 + 5 + 6 / 2 - 8 * 1 * 2
```

and This expression is getting tokenized which results in operand and operator

Comment: Maybe give us your expr and you use both operator and operand, what's that ?

Comment: How does val look like for example?

Comment: post isOperator() method implementation

Comment: isOperator method is self-codded ? What about operator and operand ?

Comment: hint: What will `val` be when tokenizing the two spaces in your input?

Comment: operator and operand here are stack of `BigInteger` and stack of `String` respectively.

Comment: how can operator be be `BigInteger` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this definition of `isOperator` it works well.

```
boolean isOperator(String s) {
   return s.equals("*") || s.equals("-") || s.equals( "/") || s.equals("+");
}

public void tokenize(String expr) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expr);
    while ( st.hasMoreElements() ) {
        String val = st.nextElement().toString();
        if ( isOperator( val ) ) {
            //operator.push(val);
            System.out.println("Val");
            System.out.println(val);
        } 
        else {
            //operand.push(op);
            System.out.println("Operand");
            BigInteger op = new BigInteger(val);
            System.out.println(op);
        }
    }
}
```

Have you used `==` to compare operators?

Comment: Sorry, ported to java from c++ after long time, you can't just loose the habit easily :)

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "4 + 5 + 6 / 2  - 8 * 1 * 2";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s);
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        String s2 = (String) tokenizer.nextElement();
        if(isArithmaticOp(s2.charAt(0))) {
            System.out.println("Op = "+s2);
        } else {
            BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(s2);
            System.out.println("Integer = "+bigInteger);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isArithmaticOp(char c) {
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '*' || c == '%'
            || c == '^';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your input expression has 2 blank spaces between 2 and -
This can result in a empty string being sent to else part of your code where BigInteger would throw an exception.

---

Ok the only way it can give you a number format exception is when your if check fails on the operand. Please post your method here.

Comment: No. have you tested it? it is not giving empty Strings.